# Codeigniter: Search and pagination

Tags: codeigniter, search, pagination

I want to search and pagination the results but the problem is only the first page works. Because I don't know how to get the search value in the next page.

Here is my code:

Search box

```
  <?php echo form_open('page/search_validation'); ?> 
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The first page I can get the search keyword by

```
 $this->input->post('search')
```

How about the other page? Because after I click the second page the search keyword becomes empty.

Comment: Use `GET` method instead `POST` and then take your search term from URL

Comment: OK so how to adjust this one ? $config['base_url']=base_url().'page/search_validation';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to form pagination config for GET method

```
$search_term= $this->input->get('search');
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('table_name')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('page/search_validation?search=' . $search_term);
```

....

Comment: Hi man, I got into another problem the page link is 2,3,4 but not 10,20,30

Comment: I mean, the first offset is 10, the next is 20 instead of 1 then 2. Because the result keep repeat the result form first page, to second page only change 1 value. Ex first 1 to 10 rows, second page should be 11-20. But I got first 1 to 10 second 2 to 11

Comment: perhaps your `limit()` paramters usage is wrong. show your limit method's params

Comment: I got it. just change $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE; to FALSE